# Connecting Informix database with .NET Provider

Tags: .net, informix, provider

I tested with testconn40 and it gives me these errors. I uninstalled and installed it again and the error persists. I disabled my firewall. I'm using a local server. In the documentation it says is:

```
SQL30081N A communication error has been detected.
Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".
Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".
Location where the error was detected: "192.168.1.200".
Communication function detecting the error: "recv".
Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0". SQLSTATE=08001
```

`*,*,0` indicates the connection was closed by the peer. This could be any network device (i.e. firewall, router, workload balancing device, etc...) between the client and DB2 server, or the DB2 server itself.

[image]

Comment: There is a lot of information missing that will be relevant.  Note that it mentions that (for Informix) you must have a DRDA listener started on a port you know and that you must attempt to connect to that port.  By default, Informix does not start a DRDA listener.  Have you configured your local Informix server to provide a DRDA listener?  If not, you'll need to do that.  If you have, then did you try to connect to the correct port?  What was the connection string that you used?  (It would help to know the version numbers of the software you're using.  Are you running on Windows?)

Comment: I'm sure that the problem is the DRDA listener that is not working, Do you know how to configure my server to provide a DRDA listener? I'm on windows, is Informix 12.10. The connection string is:                       testconn20 database=pruebas;server=127.0.0.1:19493;userid=informix;password=1234

Comment: I checked and in the installation of my local server I enabled DRDA support, I know the port that is supposed to use, but it seems that is not started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested with Informix Server 12.10 Enterprise Trial Edition, I downloaded the last fix pack https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24043166 download only the IBM DATA SERVER CLIENT for your OS, I try for the 32bits. Be sure to enable DRDA support in the installer and save the ports that it will use.

1. In etc/services search which port is using drda in the informix server in my case: dr_informix1210_2         27526/tcp

   2. In the informix directory my case: C:\Program Files\IBM Informix Software Bundle\etc open the sqlhost.informix1210_2 file.
   3. Change dr_informix1210_2 drsoctcp "yourcomputername" dr_informix1210_2 TO THIS dr_informix1210_2 drsoctcp 127.0.0.1 dr_informix1210_2
   4. Restart the server
   5. Run the command netstat -an | findstr 27526
   6. If it says it's listening run the command testconn40 database=pruebas;server=127.0.0.1:27526;userid=informix;password=1234
   7. If it's not listening the DRDA support it's not enabled, try reinstalling the server enabling it in the wizard.
   8. Finally, you can connect to Visual Studio 2015 with the IBM .NET Provider.

Comment: Some tips: I think you will want to use the MS Entity Framework, with the Informix engine. If so, you will need to install VSAI plugin, also.  If your drda listener is not started, you can start it with onmode -P start [listener_name].